# Visual Studio: Debugging with code profile(?)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm looking for a way to do debugging in Visual Studio without break point and step into code. Is there a framework or tool or maybe an option in Visual Studio 2010 that will allows you to track every step of code running without setting break point and step into?

Comment: You might take a look at [Intellitrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

IntelliTrace might be an option:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx

Comment: "This topic applies to Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate only." bummer, I only have access to VS 2010 Pro edition.